# Zend Apigility Doctrine 404 Entity Not Found Error

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, laminas-api-tools

I'm having a bit of an issue here with grabbing a value off of my entity, I think it may be related to the reflection or hydration w/in Doctrine, but I'm not sure... All I know is if I run:

`$product = $entity->getRepository('Products')->findOneBy(array('product_id' => $site->product_id));`

If I return `$product` here, I get the collection:

`{
  "product_id": 1,
  "title": "Product",
}`

But if I try to return `$product->title` I get

`{
  "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
  "title": "Not Found",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "Entity not found."
}`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A coworker helped me through this one... apparently Apigility hydrates the collection, but requires everything sent back as an array. So the object gets serialized, but the integer gets errored. So...

I changed `$product->title`

to `[$product->title]`